# Git Client for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad-app

This is regarding a search for a suitable git client for iPad, which has the following requirements:

- interface where one can visualize various repositories and commits
- pull and push
- If not free, should be reasonable priced
- supports Bitbucket, GitLab, GitHub etc

Atlassian Bitbucket does not have a native iOs app.
The most common alternatives were the following:

1. MiniBucket - does not have a good UI, dificcult to visualize directories
2. Git+ - does not support Bitbucket
3. Working Copy - the free version does not allow "push".

Comment: Could you put a number on the reasonable price? Working Copy has a single purchase upgrade to unlock all features. What makes it unreasonable?